# VS2008 build solution script with VC++ include and library folder

Tags: windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, build-script

I am trying to create build script with VS2008

```
call "%VS90COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat" > NUL
echo working on my_solution.sln...
devenv "my_solution.sln" /build "%Release|win32" /out "make.log"
```

The thing is that I want to add VC++ include file folder and library folder in script, not in solution config because in other PCs, these folders may be located in different place.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: use environment variables.

Before invoking `devenv`, extend the `INCLUDE` and `LIB` environment variables:

```
call "%VS90COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat" > NUL
echo working on my_solution.sln...

SET INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;d:\your\path\to\your\include\folder
SET LIB=%LIB%;d:\your\path\to\your\lib\folder

devenv "my_solution.sln" /build "%Release|win32" /out "make.log"
```

Alternately you could also do this:

Update the solution to reference `%MY_PRIVATE_INCLUDE%` and `%MY_PRIVATE_LIB%` as additional directories in the solution's Include and Link settings.  Then just assign these values at build time.

```
call "%VS90COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat" > NUL
echo working on my_solution.sln...

SET MY_PRIVATE_INCLUDE=d:\your\path\to\your\include\folder
SET MY_PRIVATE_LIB=%LIB%;d:\your\path\to\your\lib\folder

devenv "my_solution.sln" /build "%Release|win32" /out "make.log"
```